# QProcess:startDetached open application but does not find argument

Tags: qt, pdf, qprocess

I'm trying to run Evince to read a pdf file from my Qt program, using QProcess::startDetached method :

```
QProcess myProcess = QProcess();
myProcess.startDetached("evince", "~/mypath/doc.pdf");
```

Evince is well launched, but in its HMI I get the message "Cannot open the file, No such file or directory"

But the path is ok as when I use "acroread" to read the file, it finds the file and can open it.

Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tilde character is a shell shortcut, it doesn't necessarily mean anything for any other program.

For a shell it means the equivalent of `$HOME`.
`acrocread` might be a shell script and implicitly expand the argument before launching the actual application, `evince` is probably the program itself so you'll have to expand that yourself.

E.g.

```
QDir homeDir = QDir::home();
QFileInfo fileInfo(homeDir, "mypath/doc.pdf");

QProcess::startDetached("evince", QStringList() << fileInfo.absoluteFilePath());
```

If you want to open the PDF in the user's reader of choice, see `QDesktopServices::openUrl()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to send full path `/home/user/mypath/doc.pdf`?

Try also to call it with one parameter:

```
myProcess.startDetached("evince ~/mypath/doc.pdf");
```

Comment: When I send the full path it doesn't work, but calling in one parameter works, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had the same problem and couldn't make it work. However this worked for me:

```
QString commandLine = command + " " + parameter;
int result = QProcess::execute(commandLine.toLatin1());
```